# Cordova play game services login flow inconsistent

Tags: android, cordova, google-play-services

using the cordova plugin

```
cordova-plugin-play-games-services
```

and a very strange thing is happening.  There are two parts to it.

The first time you run

```
window.plugins.playGamesServices.auth()
```

it will simply log you in, no problems there.  now I have a button that you click to log in / out.  when you click on it it will log you out because you are logged in.  no problem there.

```
window.plugins.playGamesServices.signOut()
```

however, when you click on the button again and run the above command it will then prompt you to chose an account (but it didn't the first time, it just logged you into one).  Okay, so I click on one of them, it starts to go, then just stops.  but it's not logged in.  it will no longer log in and the button stops working.

this is on a device I cannot connect to the computer, I'm not sure how to get any errors / logs.  I don't even know what to alert as far as an error goes.

so the question is, why is it working the first time without asking to log into one of the 3 accounts?  and why is it asking for the three accounts the second time and not logging in?

```
EDIT:
```

Sometimes it will AUTH with the default account and sometimes (rarely) it will ask you to choose the account the first time.  When this happens and you chose an account, it works fine.  It's only once you disconnect and try to reconnect that there is some kind of issue with the AUTH function.

and it gets stranger still.  if I close the app and reopen it then it will work again.  SOMETIMES probably about 50% it will AUTH correctly the first time, logout, then AUTH a 2nd time.  but never on the third.  but this is only after closing the app down after installing it.

it seems to me that there is some kind of variable in the plugin that isn't getting reset or something, but I don't know much about the plugin, google play services or how it all works together.

Comment: Have you tried to check if sign in was successful with this function?
window.plugins.playGamesServices.isSignedIn(function (result) {
    // ‘result’ is a JSON object with a single boolean property of ‘isSignedIn’
    // {
    //      “isSignedIn” : true
    // }

    console.log(“Do something with result.isSignedIn”);
});

Comment: yes, everything works fine until the second time AUTH is called and then it does nothing.  it doesn't perform the success call back or the failed call back, it just doesn't do anything (after selecting an account)